# Как из input взять значение и подставить в iframe

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Введите название">
            <button>Поиск</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="iframe">
        <iframe src="https://site.ru?search='Здесь тест из input'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="origin" width="800" height="452"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А с чем именно возникли сложности? Просто надо по нажатию на кнопку взять значение value инпута и изменить атрибут src у iframe

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку подставлялось значение в iframe из input

Comment: Это понятно, но сайт во фрейме Ваш?

Comment: Нет сайт не мой

Comment: Я понять не могу а в чем проблема? Я нашел такое решение но только для подставления в ссылку <input type="number" id="quantity" value="1" >
<a href="http://site.ru/page?id=1&quantity='сюда подставить данные из input'" id="link">нажать</a>

<script>
link.onclick = function(e) {
  this.setAttribute('href',this.getAttribute('href').replace("сюда подставить данные из input",quantity.value));
}
</script>

Comment: Закиньте этот код в свой вопрос читать не возможно.

Comment: По сути Ваш вопрос сводится к вопросу как поменять `аттрибут` у `DOM элемента`, то что тут `iframe` вообще не важно — это базовый вопрос, хорошо освещенный в документации [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myButton = document.getElementById("button");

myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    iframe.src = "https://site.ru?search=" + name;
    alert(iframe.src);
    }
);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Введите название" id="name" value="">
            <button id="button">Поиск</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="iframe">
        <iframe src="" id="iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="origin" width="800" height="452"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем `alert` то?

Comment: Как альтернатива `console.log()` :)